# How do I convert one column of a csv file to a txt file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, txt

I have a specific column in a csv file and I want to write each row of that column as a newline in the same txt file. I'm using Panda if that helps. I can't quite figure out how to iterate over the rows of one specific column.

Comment: Non-Python answer: `cut -d';' -f<column-number>`. ;-)

Comment: Do you want to append a column data to same csv file from which you are reading data? Or to a new txt file?

Comment: Will you please edit your question and include a small sample input, and how "each row of that column as a newline" looks "in the same txt file"? thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
dataframe[colname].to_csv('filepath.txt', sep="\n", index=False)
```

add `header = False` if you don't need the column name in that .txt file